# Weird syntax error

Tags: idris

```
data A = B | C Int

implementation Semigroup A where
  B <+> x = x
  x <+> B = x
  C m <+> C n = C (m + n)
```

gives me a syntax error of

```
./Nodes/Test.idr:3:1: error: expected: ";",
    "|", declaration, end of input
implementation Semigroup A where 
^                                
Type checking ./Nodes/Test.idr
```

in Idris 0.11.2.  Removing `implementation` gives instead this message:

```
./Nodes/Test.idr:3:13: error: expected: "@",
    "with", argument expression,
    constraint argument,
    function right hand side,
    implicit function argument,
    with pattern
Semigroup A where 
            ^     
Type checking ./Nodes/Test.idr
```

Should I get an error message?  I can't see anything wrong with the syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use infix operators in implementations (for now, I guess). Instead, wrap them to prefixes:

```
data A = B | C Int

implementation Semigroup A where
  (<+>) B x = x
  (<+>) x B = x
  (<+>) (C m) (C n) = C (m + n)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.